# Search functionality not working in Chrome extension to display and navigate tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a Chrome extension that displays all open tabs and allows users to click on a title to navigate to the corresponding tab. I'm trying to implement a search bar to filter the displayed tabs based on the user's input, but the search functionality is not working as expected. I want the results to update dynamically.

here is my popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
  var myTabsArray = tabs;
  console.log("Number of open tabs:", tabs.length);

  var tabContainer = document.getElementById("tab-container");
  myTabsArray.forEach(function (tab) {
    var tabElement = document.createElement("div");
    tabElement.textContent = tab.title;
    tabElement.className = "tabs";

    tabElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
      chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true });
    });

    tabContainer.appendChild(tabElement);
  });
});
function search_tab() {
  let input = document.getElementById("searchbar").value;
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (!x[i].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}

Here is my Popup.HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tabify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Tabify - Tab Manager</h1>
    <div class="topnav"> 
      <input type="text" id="searchbar" 
      placeholder="Search for a tab..." oninput="search_tab()">
    </div>
    <div id="tab-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```